# How can I multiple datepicker modal in vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, datepicker, vue-component, vuetify.js

My vue component like this :

```
<template>
  <v-row>
    <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
      <v-dialog
        v-for="(item, i) in test" :key="i"
        ref="dialog"
        v-model="modal"
        :return-value.sync="item.date"
        persistent
        width="290px"
      >
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
          <v-text-field
            v-model="item.date"
            label="Picker in dialog"
            prepend-icon="event"
            readonly
            v-on="on"
          ></v-text-field>
        </template>
        <v-date-picker v-model="date" scrollable>
          <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>
          <v-btn text color="primary" @click="modal = false">Cancel</v-btn>
          <v-btn text color="primary" @click="$refs.dialog.save(item.date)">OK</v-btn>
        </v-date-picker>
      </v-dialog>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      test: [
        { id: 1, date: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10) },
        { id: 2, date: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10) },
      ],
      modal: false,
    }),
  }
</script>
```

multiple datetimepicker doesn't work properly

if i click ok button in the modal, there exist error like this :

[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: _vm.$refs.dialog.save is not a function"

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to return the whole object from the dialog, not just the date. With `:return-value.sync="item.date"`, the objects in `test` will have only `date` as their only property. Your date picker also has a wrong binding.

```
  <v-dialog
    v-for="(item, i) in test" :key="i"
    ref="dialog"
    v-model="modal"
    :return-value.sync="item"
    persistent
    width="290px"
  >
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
      <v-text-field
        v-model="item.date"
        label="Picker in dialog"
        prepend-icon="event"
        readonly
        v-on="on"
      ></v-text-field>
    </template>
    <v-date-picker v-model="item.date" scrollable>
      <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>
      <v-btn text color="primary" @click="modal = false">OK</v-btn>
    </v-date-picker>
  </v-dialog>
```

Comment: there exist error : `vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "function () { return this._data.$$state }": "Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers."`